# python-iptables how to specify multi argument matches

Tags: python, python-iptables

How do I specify multi-argument matches with [python-iptables](http://ldx.github.io/python-iptables/index.html)?

For example, the following `iptables` command:

```
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
```

If I create the following:

```
import iptc
rule = iptc.Rule()
rule.src = '1.1.1.1'
rule.protocol = 'tcp'
t = rule.create_target('DROP')
m = rule.create_match('tcp')
m.tcp_flags = 'FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN'
```

it will complain:

```
ValueError: invalid value FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN
```

**PS:** I know that for my particular example, I can simply use `m.syn = '1'`, but I'm trying to generalize on *how* to specify multi-argument matches.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version? See this [issue](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables/issues/26).

Comment: Aaah, I see... btw, your answer came in just seconds before I actually found that page myself. My Google-fu is getting rusty, it seems :/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Okay... someone tried to post an answer, but he/she deleted it when I was commenting on it.

The answer attempt was:

```
m.tcp_flags = ['FIN', 'SYN', 'RST', 'ACK SYN']
```

which gave the wrong result:

```
print m.parameters
{u'tcp_flags': u'FIN SYN'}
```

However, that inspired me to try the following:

```
m.tcp_flags = ['FIN,SYN,RST,ACK', 'SYN']
```

which gives:

```
>>> match.parameters
{u'tcp_flags': u'FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN'}
```

Committing that rule into the `INPUT` chain and running `iptables-save` shows that it properly returns the rule I want.

So, thank you!